# Suppose $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and $f \in \mathcal{R}[c, b]$ for all $a < c < b$. Show $f \in \mathcal{R}[a, b]$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Question:

> Suppose $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and $f \in\mathcal{R}[c, b]$ for all $a < c < b$. Show $f \in \mathcal{R}[a, b]$.

where $\mathcal{R}[x,y]$ is the space of Riemann-integrable functions on $[x,y]$ ($x<y$)

Use this to show that the following function: 
$$f(x) =\begin{cases} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &\text{ if } x \neq 0\\
 0 &\text{ if } x=0
\end{cases}$$

is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

I understand how to show a function is integrable if it's a more concrete problem, but it's harder for me here, since I don't know how to construct the partition properly here.

Comment: What does the notation R[c,b] stand for? Space of functions that are Riemann integrable on $[c,b]$?

Comment: Yup, sorry about that. I just realized that people might not get that notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any partition of $[a,b]$ into parts $<\delta$, the Riemann upper and lower sum differ by less than $\epsilon$.

Let $M=\sup |f|<\infty$. Then given $\epsilon>0$ we can pick suitable $c\in(a,b)$ (according to conditions elaborated below). Then, we find $\delta>0$ such that the difference between upper and lower sum for any fine enough partition of $[c,b]$ is sufficiently small.
We hope that it is possible to fill in the details suchthat for any partition of $[a,b]$ finer than $\delta$ the difference between upper and lower sum is less than $\epsilon$.
So consider any partition of $[a,b]$ into parts $<\delta$. Refine this partition by introducing one additional point at $c$, if necessary. This may lower the difference between upper and lower sum, but at most by $2M\delta$. Also, the contribution of $[a,c]$ to the difference of upper and lower sum is at most $2M(c-a)$. And the contribution of $[c,b]$ is at most ... whatever we can still afford, let's call this $\epsilon'$.
In summary, the difference between upper and lower sum of the original partition of $[a,b]$ is
$$ <2M\delta+2M(c-a)+\epsilon'$$
and we want this to be $<\epsilon$. So we

- pick $c$ small enough such that $2M(c-a)<\frac\epsilon3$
- let $\epsilon'=\frac\epsilon3$
- pick $\delta$ small enough such that $2M\delta<\frac\epsilon3$ **and** the difference between upper and lower sum on $[c,b]$ is less than $\epsilon'$ for all partitions of $[c,b]$ finer than $\delta$

Then as seen, every partition of $[a,b]$ finer than $\delta$make ste difference between upper and lower sum on $[a,b]$ less than $\epsilon$.