# How do I show that if $f$ is integrable on $[c,b]$ for all $c \in [a,b]$, then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $a < b$. Suppose that the function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and Riemann integrable on $[c,b]$ for every $a < c < b$. Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and that

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \lim_{c \to a} \int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx$$

I can see that it is true, but I honestly have no idea how to prove that.

My thought would be to show that the upper and lower sums are equal:
$$U(f) = L(f) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$$
In terms of epsilon-delta, I would want to show that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) \leq \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: $$\int_a^b=\int_c^b+\int_a^c.$$

Comment: I had thought about that. However, I'm not sure how it would help me prove this. I still have the limit on the right side, and I can't seem to get rid of it even with breaking it apart. Can you give me some more steps?

Comment: First show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ using an argument similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3925684/148510). In that question it is assumed that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b]$ but from the answer you see that all that is needed is your condition that $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[c,b]$ for all $c> a$.

Comment: @RRl I am aware of that link, but I really do not have a better way to ask this question. I am completely lost so I needed to post it. From your explanation, I am still not quite sure where to go. I'm not sure I understand how being RI on [c,b] suffices rather than continuity. I also do not see how this shows the equality. I am just not seeing anything from these replies. I am still completely lost.

Comment: Ultimately you want to show that $\left|\int_a^bf(x) \, dx - \int_c^b f(x) \, dx \right| < \epsilon$ for all $c$ sufficiently close to $a$.

Comment: @RRL Hmm. I am not seeing how that result would prove the desired claim. There is still no limit involved, so how would showing that show the equality?

Comment: What is the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of $\lim_{c \to a} I_c = \int_a^b f(x) \, dx$? Also, do you know the Riemann criterion for showing that a function is Riemann integrable?

Comment: Nothing in that linked answer uses continuity other than it implies Riemann integrability of $f$ over $[c,b]$ for every $c>a$ which is your hypothesis here.  So to do this problem you need to know some sufficient condition for Riemann integrability. I could show you the answer but it would essentially be a duplicate of that answer changing $0$ to $a$ etc.

Comment: @RRL my thoughts would be to show that the upper and lower sums are equal. $U(f) = L(f) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ In terms of epsilon-delta, I would want to show that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) \leq \epsilon$

Comment: You mean upper and lower "integrals" $U(f)$ and $L(f)$...  Also you mean there exists a partition $P$ given any $\epsilon$ such that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$ -- correct?

Comment: @RRL I do not have any thoughts. As I said, I do not know how to start. The things I listed were in replies to your conversation, not thoughts I had about the problem. And as you can, the hints have not gotten me anywhere. So I still have no idea how to approach the problem

Comment: Do you know how to prove that a function is Riemann integrable? The standard way is to start with an arbitrary $\epsilon >0$ and find a partition $P$ of $[a, b] $ for which $U(f, P) - L(f, P) <\epsilon$. Now try to find a partition of $[a, b] $ here. You can first choose $c$ near $a$ and get a partition $P'$ of $[c, b] $ (function is integrable there) and then take $P=P'\cup\{a\} $. Write out formal details and let us know if you face any issues.

Comment: In general questions which contain "no idea where to start" are not encouraged here. Please feel free to edit your post with some context and some idea about the problem. The question is routine and it is expected that students come with some solution (even halfway) with little help.

Comment: Bound $\displaystyle\int_a^c$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I know the definition that I listed, but I am still not sure how to apply it here. I don't see any details I can write out. Just writing the definition isn't helping me on this question since I don't know how to apply it. I guess I just have to face that I can't get help on this question and it will likely close.

Comment: Try this simple exercise first. Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ except at some point $c$ and $f$ is bounded. Can you use the definition to prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$. If you can do this, then you can also solve this question.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1541836/72031) and its answer.

Comment: The second part about limits is a standard corollary of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ then the integral function $F(x) =\int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ is continuous on $[a, b] $.

Comment: @DominicBlanco I've copy-pasted one of your comments into the body of the question.  I still think that this question could use some more details, but your willingness to engage with folk in the comments, even if that engagement has not been overly productive, seems to demonstrate a willingness to work.  That being said, I still think that it is quite likely that this question will be closed---folk's standards for what is and is not acceptable on this site vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you establish that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ (for example as shown by Xander Henderson) there are several ways to proceed in showing that

$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \lim_{c \to a+} \int_c^b f(x) \, dx$$

(1) Use the fact that if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, then it is integrable on any subinterval and

$$\left|\int_a^b f(x) \, dx - \int_c^b f(x) \, dx \right| = \left|\int_a^c f(x) \, dx \right| \leqslant \int_a^c|f(x)| \, dx \\\leqslant \sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)|\cdot (c-a) \underset{c \to a+}\longrightarrow 0$$

This argument obviously invokes several basic properties of the Riemann integral without proof.

For more of a "first principles" proof ...

(2)  There exists a partition $P: a = x_0< x_1=c< \ldots < x_n =b$ such that for any Riemann sum $S(P,f) = \sum_{j=1}^n f(\xi_j)(x_j - x_{j-1})$, we have

$$\left|\int_a^bf(x) \, dx-S(P,f)\right|= \left|\int_a^bf(x) \, dx-\sum_{j=1}^n f(\xi_j)(x_j - x_{j-1})\right|< \frac{\epsilon}{3},$$

and by refining the partition if necessary we can assume that with $M = \sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)|$,

$$c-a = x_1-a < \frac{\epsilon}{3M}, \\ \left|\int_c^bf(x) \, dx-S(P',f)\right|=\left|\int_c^bf(x) \, dx-\sum_{j=2}^n f(\xi_j)(x_j - x_{j-1})\right|< \frac{\epsilon}{3}$$

Thus, for every $a< c < a+\frac{\epsilon}{3M}$,

$$ \left|\int_a^bf(x) \, dx-\int_c^bf(x) \, dx \right|\\ \leqslant \left|\int_a^bf(x) \, dx-S(P,f)\right|+ |S(P,f) - S(P',f)|+\left|\int_c^bf(x) \, dx-S(P',f)\right|\\ \leqslant \frac{2\epsilon}{3} + |f(\xi_1)|(x_1-a)\leqslant \frac{2\epsilon}{3} + M(x_1-a)< \epsilon,$$

and, therefore,

$$\lim_{c \to a+} \int_c^b f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(x) \, dx$$

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the conclusion to both parts. On 1.), I see that you got the last term to approach $0$. But how does that show that these are equal? I see that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx \leq Sup |f(x)| * (c - a)$. Taking the limit as $c \to a$, I'd think this shows $\lim_{c \to a} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx \leq 0$. Great, so the integral is $0$, but what does that tell us about its equality to the other? On 2.), I'm kind at a similar point in terms of the conclusion. I'm thinking, "ok great, it's less than $\epsilon$. I don't see the conclusion." Does it make sense what I'm asking?

Comment: @DominicBlanco: I showed $0\leqslant \left|\int_a^b f(x) \, dx - \int_c^b f(x) \, dx \right| \leqslant \sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)|\cdot (c-a) $.  I added the $0$ on the left since an absolute value is obviously nonegative.  The limit of the RHS as $c \to a$ is $0$ so by the squeeze theorem, we have $\lim_{c \to a+} \left|\int_a^b f(x) \, dx - \int_c^b f(x) \, dx \right| = 0$.  That means $\lim_{c \to a+}\int_c^b f(x) \, dx = \int_c^b f(x) \, dx $.  Hopefully that is understandable.

Comment: The second part proves the limit by an $\epsilon - \delta$ argument.  I showed that if $a < c < a+\delta = a+ \frac{\epsilon}{3M}$, then $\left|\int_a^b f(x) \, dx - \int_c^b f(x) \, dx \right| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Ahhhhh I see it now. Wow all it took was for me to "see" the 0 on the left side because of the absolute value. I guess that fully confirms I am a visual learner. And I was thinking of the epsilon-delta in the wrong context. This argument IS the limit, so of course it won't appear in the problem. I get that one now too. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

While there are certainly slicker proofs than what I am about to present, it does not seem unreasonable to work directly from the definitions.  My feeling is that an elementary proof gives one a better idea of what the definitions and theorems actually mean, and are therefore, in some respects, more enlightening.

> **Definitions:**  Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded.  Let
> $$P = \{ a = x_0 < x_1 < \dotsb < x_n = b\} $$
> be a partition of $[a,b]$, and for each $j = 1, 2, \dots, n$, define
> $$ m_j = \inf_{x_{j-1} \le x \le x_j} f(x)
> \qquad\text{and}\qquad
> M_j = \sup_{x_{j-1}\le x \le x_j} f(x). $$
> The *lower* and *upper Riemann sum* subordinate to $P$ are
> $$
> L(f,[a,b],P) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} m_j (x_{j} - x_{j-1})
> $$
> and
> $$
> U(f,[a,b],P) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} M_j (x_{j} - x_{j-1}),
> $$
> respectively.  The *lower* and *upper Riemann integrals* are
> $$ L(f,[a,b]) = \sup \{ L(f,[a,b],P) : \text{$P$ is a partition of $[a,b]$} \} $$
> and
> $$
> U(f,[a,b]) = \inf \{ U(f,[a,b],P) : \text{$P$ is a partition of $[a,b]$} \},
> $$
> respectively.  If $L(f) = U(f)$, then we say that $f$ is *Riemann integrable* on $[a,b]$, and define the *Riemann integral* to be the common value, i.e.
> $$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = L(f) = U(f). $$

Note that for any partition $P$,
$$ L(f,[a,b],P) \le L(f, [a,b]) \le U(f,[a,b]) \le U(f,[a,b],P). $$
In order to show that a function is Riemann integrable, it is therefore sufficient to show that
$$ U(f,[a,b]) - L(f,[a,b]) \le U(f,[a,b],P) - L(f,[a,b], P) $$
can be made arbitrarily small by choosing an appropriate partition of $[a,b]$.  It is also worth noting that if we refine a partition, the upper and lower sums "behave nicely".  This is encapsulated in the following lemma, which I will state without proof.

> **Lemma:** Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$, and let $P'$ be a *refinement* of $P$ (that is, $P'$ contains all of the points in $P$, and possibly more).  Then
> $$ L(f,[a,b],P) \le L(f,[a,b],P') \le U(f,[a,b],P') \le U(f,[a,b],P). $$

The basic idea of the proof is that
$$ \bigl( \sup_{x_{j-1} \le x \le x_j} x \bigr) \bigl( x_j - x_{j-1} \bigr)
\le 
\bigl( \sup_{x_{j-1} \le x \le x'} x \bigr) \bigl( x_j - x' \bigr) + \bigl( \sup_{x' \le x \le x_j} x \bigr) \bigl( x_j - x' \bigr) $$
for any $x' \in [x_{j-1}, x_j]$.  Thought about carefully, this lets us bound $L(f,[a,b],P)$ from above by $L(f,[a,b],P')$.  As similar argument will work for the upper Riemann sums.

In order to prove the desired result, we need to get control on the lower and upper Riemann sums, which will allow us to control the lower and upper Riemann integrals.  The essential idea is that we can control the sums on $[a,c]$ by choosing $c$ sufficiently close to $a$, and we can control the sums on $[c,b]$ via the Riemann integrability of $f$ on every such interval.

More precisely, choose $\varepsilon > 0$.  As $f$ is bounded, there exist $m$ and $M$ such that $m \le f(x) \le M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.  Chose $x_1 > a$ so that
$$ (M-m) (x_1 - a) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. $$
Since $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[x_1,b]$, there exists a partition $P_1$ of $[x_1,b]$ such that
$$ \int_{x_1}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x 
= L(f,[x_1,b])
< L(f,[x_1,b],P_1) + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}. $$
Note that this follows from the definition of $L(f,[x_1,b])$ as a supremum.  Similarly, there is a partition $P_2$ of $[x_1,b]$ such that
$$ \int_{x_1}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x 
= U(f,[x_1,b])
> U(f,[x_1,b],P_1) - \frac{\varepsilon}{4}. $$
Take $P' = \{ x_1 < x_2 < \dotsb < x_n = b\}$ to be any common refinement of $P_1$ and $P_2$, e.g. $P' = P_1 \cup P_2$, and define
$$ P = \{ a = x_0 < x_1 < \dotsb < x_n = b\}. $$
Note that $P$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, and that
\begin{align*}
&U(f,[a,b]) - L(f,[a,b]) \\
&\qquad\le U(f,[a,b],P) - L(f,[a,b],P) \\
&\qquad= \sum_{j=1}^{n} M_j (x_{j} - x_{j-1}) - \sum_{j=1}^{n} m_j (x_{j} x_{j-1}) \\
&\qquad= (M-m) (x_1 - a) + \sum_{j=2}^{n} M_j (x_{j} - x_{j-1}) - \sum_{j=2}^{n} m_j (x_{j} x_{j-1}) \\
&\qquad< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + U(f,[x_1,b],P') - L(f,[x_1,b], P') \\
&\qquad\le \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + U(f,[x_1,b],P_2) - L(f,[x_1,b], P_1) && \text{(by the lemma)} \\
&\qquad< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \left( U(f,[x_1,b]) + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} \right) - \left( L(f,[x_1,b]) - \frac{\varepsilon}{4} \right) \\
&\qquad= \varepsilon,
\end{align*}
with the last equality following from the fact that $L(f,[x_1,b]) = U(f,[x_1,b])$.  This completes the proof, as we have shown that the difference between the lower and upper Riemann integrals can be made arbitrarily small by choosing an appropriate partition.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119090/discussion-on-answer-by-xander-henderson-how-do-i-show-that-if-f-is-integrable).

Answer (score 2):

A function $f$ bounded it is Riemann integrable if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere, i.e., the set of discontinuities has measure $0$. Since for all $c>a$, $f$ it is Riemann integrable on $[c,b]$ it follows that the set of discontinuities on $[c,b]$ has measure $0$, therefore on $[a,b]$.

Comment: This answer is correct but way beyond what the asker can handle. I doubt if this really will help. I don't like  using a cannon to kill a fly.

Comment: @Valerin Now that I've gone through and understood some of the other answers, I'd like to come to this one. I am just starting to work with Lebesgue measure, so do note I am very much a novice here. Why can you make the conclusion that the measure has to be $0$ on $[a,b]$? I could agree that it should be $0$ on $(a,b]$ since $c > a$ can be made arbitrarily close to $a$, but why can we make the conclusion that it must be ture on $[a,b]$?

Comment: Well I just wanted to point out other way of looking at the problem. @DominicBlanco adding another isolated point as "a" do not change the conclusion it remains  measure 0.

Comment: So $a$ is an isolated point? Is that a name for a specific kind of point? I haven't heard of that.

Comment: Well I mean, adding a single point "which has no area" or mass, i.e. measure 0, the result remains the same. You could add a countable set of single points, indeed. But for this particular case what make sense is add "a" as the function is defined on $[a, b] $

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is bounded say $|f(x)\le M$, then $|\int _a^cf(x)dx|\le \int _a^c|f(x)|dx\le M(c-a)\to 0$

Comment: How does this help me answer the question though? So I would have $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx - 0$. So this means I can substitue and get $\int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx = \lim_{c \to a} \int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx$. However, I'm still not sure how this makes the conclusion. I still haven't done anything with the limit. Can you give me some more steps please?